# horizontal scrolling Angular 7

Tags: angular, types

I have a problem. Scrolling doesn't work. I suppose there is no scrollTo in agular 7. There is some other solution?. This is a code snippet from .ts

```
 @ViewChild('flexibleHeaderWrap', { read: ElementRef }) private flexibleHeaderWrap: ElementRef;
    
      public scrollRight(): void {
        this.flexibleHeaderMenu.nativeElement.scrollTo({ left: this.flexibleHeaderMenu.nativeElement.scrollLeft + 150, behavior: 'smooth' });
      }
    
      public scrollLeft(): void {
        this.flexibleHeaderMenu.nativeElement.scrollTo({ left: this.flexibleHeaderMenu.nativeElement.scrollLeft - 150, behavior: 'smooth' });

  }
```

greetings

Comment: You mean horizontal scrolling on mobile device ? If so, look at HammerModule in angular 9+ and hammerjs import in  angular 7

Comment: Does your template have an element that has a template reference of `flexibleHeaderWrap`? Additionally, your code inside of `scrollRight` and `scrollLeft` are actually referencing a different variable altogether.

Comment: Twen Only in desktop version :)

Edric I have  reference of flexibleHeaderWrap

Comment: are you getting any errors in console ?